# Formatting price

Tags: asp.net

i want to display my price value like after decimal point only two digits to display.
i try this.

```
lblDiscount.Text = string.Format("{0:c} ", Convert.ToString(sDis));
```

but it is displaying three digits after point.
can you please tell me how to format price

Answer (score 3):

From [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) on MSDN:

```
decimal value = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:C2}.", value);
// Displays "Your account balance is $123.46."
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the type of sDis, but try using -

```
lblDiscount.Text = sDis.ToString("#0.00");
```

or you can try using -

```
lblDiscount.Text = Convert.ToDouble(sDis).ToString("#0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Reqad up on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

and then follow the links until you reach custom formatting.

Answer (score 0):

assuming sDis is a decimal value, you do not need to use Convert.ToString() on it within the string.Format() call.

I would replace what you have with:

```
lblDiscount.Text = string.Format("{0:C2}", sDis);
```

or even just

```
lblDiscount.Text = sDis.ToString("C2");
```

Answer (score 0):

if sDis is double then

```
lblDiscount.Text = sDis.ToString("#.##");
```